# jQuery/PHP Replace Text with Title

Tags: php, jquery

Trying to replace the Text inside an `<h1>` with the text inside the `<title>` with jQuery.

```
$('.pagination').each(function(
    $('.pagination h1').replace($("html head title").text(););
);
```

I don't really know how to do this, I sorta hacked it together.

EDIT:  Or, does anyone know how to do this with PHP?

Comment: Doing it in PHP?  We really can't help you with that unless you show us how PHP is displaying the page.  Well, you can just save the title as a variable and then print it in place of the h1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
$('h1').text($("title").text());
```

Replaces every `h1` text in the document with the text inside the `title` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the title of the page using `document.title`.  Instead of using `.each` you can just target all h1 tags.

```
$('.pagination h1').text(document.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h1').html( $('title').text() );
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
title=document.title;
$("h1").html(title);
```